# Properties of expectations of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw this in some article but can't show it.
Suppose $X,Y$ and $Z$ are i.i.d. random variables and there exists functions $f, F$ such that for all $C \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\Bbb E[f(Y-C)] = \Bbb E[X F(X-C)],$$
then we have $$\Bbb E[f(Y-Z)] = \Bbb E[X F(X-Z)].$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ denote the common distribution function of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, since they are independent, their joint distributions are product probability measures, thus
\begin{align*}
& E[XF(X - Z)] \\
= & \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} xF(x - z) dG(x)dG(z) \\
= & \int_\mathbb{R}E[XF(X - z)]dG(z) \\
= & \int_\mathbb{R}E[f(Y - z)] dG(z) \quad \text{ by condition}\\
= & \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(y - z) dG(y)dG(z) \\
= & E[f(Y - Z)]
\end{align*}